# TableView Not Updating After Item Is Added To Array

Tags: swift, tableview

I am building an app that uses the Twitter API to post to a user's Twitter and load those tweets in a TableView. The table loads correctly when the app first launches. However, after composing and posting a Tweet (confirmed that the Tweet is posted and in the array) the table view is still displaying the same tweets prior without the newly created one. I thought it might have something to do with the asynchronous code so I implemented the `DispatchQueue` in the `refreshData()` function. The table view is still not loading the most recently added tweet. How can I change the `refreshData()` function so that the table updates when Tweet is posted successfully?

```
import UIKit
import OAuthSwift

class FeedViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetText: UITextField!

    var user: User!
    var tweets = [Tweet]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 200
        let consumerSecret = user.consumerSecret
        let consumerKey = user.consumerKey
        let oAuthToken = user.oAuthToken
        let oAuthSecret = user.oAuthSecret
        let oauthswift = user.oauthswift
        let screen_name = user.screen_name


        print("Feed Consumer Secret: \(consumerSecret)")
        print("Feed Consumer Key: \(consumerKey)")
        print("Feed Auth Token: \(oAuthToken)")
        print("Feed Auth Secret: \(oAuthSecret)")
        print("Screen Name: \(screen_name)")

        loadFeed(oauthswift: oauthswift)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func postButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
        let oauthswift = user.oauthswift
        let url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status="
        let tweet_url = tweetText.text
        let encoded_tweet = tweet_url?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlHostAllowed)
        let new_url = url + encoded_tweet!
        let _ = oauthswift.client.post(
            new_url, parameters: [:],
            success: { response in
                let dataString = response.string!
                let jsonDict = try? response.jsonObject()
                let jsonDict2 = jsonDict as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                let tweetText2 = jsonDict2["text"]!
                let jsonDict4 = jsonDict2["user"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                let username = jsonDict4["screen_name"]!
                let newTweet = Tweet(tweetText: tweetText2 as! String, username: username as! String)
                self.tweets.append(newTweet)
                print(username)
                //print(dataString)
                self.loadFeed(oauthswift: oauthswift)
                self.tweetText.text = ""

        },
            failure: { error in
                print(error)
        }
        )
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell") as? PostCell {
            cell.configureCell(tweet: tweet)
            return cell

        } else {
            return PostCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets.count
    }

    func loadFeed(oauthswift: OAuth1Swift){
                print("LOAD FEED")
                let _ = oauthswift.client.get(
                    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=\(user.screen_name)", parameters: [:],
                    success: { response in
                        let jsonDict = try? response.jsonObject()
                        let jsonDict2 = jsonDict as! Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>
                        let arrayCount = jsonDict2.count
                        for index in 0...arrayCount - 1 {
                            let jsonDict4 = jsonDict2[index]["user"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>
                            let tweetText = jsonDict2[index]["text"]!
                            let username = jsonDict4["screen_name"]!
                            let newTweet = Tweet(tweetText: tweetText as! String, username: username as! String)
                            self.tweets.append(newTweet)
                            print(tweetText)
                        }

                        self.refreshData()

                }, failure: { error in
                    print(error)
                }
                )

    }

    func refreshData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

**PostCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var userLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tweetLabel: UILabel!

    var tweet: Tweet!

    func configureCell(tweet: Tweet) {

        self.userLabel.text = "@\(tweet.username)"
        self.tweetLabel.text = tweet.tweetText
        print(tweet.tweetText)

    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Which is the first line of your code that does not do as you expect?  You need to debug this with debugger and let us know the line and what the unexpected result is.  Put breakpoints everywhere as this is async.

Comment: Any chance this is due to the `&count=10` at the end of the queried url?

Comment: You are doing one thing wrong. After you post to twiiter don't you get the post's object in response? If yes, then don't call loadFeed, use that object to append to "tweets"  array.

Comment: @Cabus I agree, this might be the case.

Comment: @Cabus I changed it to pull in all records (see Edit above) and I am still not seeing the latest tweet. When I re-run the app, the latest tweet is there.

Comment: @Naresh I added the tweet to the array when I posted and I am still not seeing the latest tweet without re-running the app (see edited code above).

Comment: Need to see your configureCell method.  And put a print statement in that method and dump out tweets property.

Comment: @Smartcat I added the configureCell method and added the print statement for the tweet text.

Comment: @EricWalters remove these 2 lines after you append the tweet self.loadFeed(oauthswift: oauthswift)
                self.tweetText.text = "" and add self.tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sure that Twitter accepted the post and you appended the new Tweet to the data source there is no need for a full reloadData. You can display just the new row in the table.

In `FeedViewController`, in method `postButtonPushed`, inside the `oauthswift.client.post`'s success clousure right after this line `self.tweets.append(newTweet)` add this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(item: self.tweets.count-1, section: 0)],
                              with: .automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```